# WPF ComboBox get highlighted item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, highlight

I'm trying to get the value of the highlighted item of the dropdown list in a `ComboBox` while the dropdown list is still open.

This is because I want to show a different `ToolTip` for all the element in the dropdown list based on the highlighted item.

I have found some information here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/822f85e7-524a-4af2-b09a-c88c94971ac0/identifying-the-highlighted-item-in-a-combobox
but seems to be difficult and with a lot of code behind...

I have also try to use the `IsHighlighted` property of `ComboBoxItem` on `SelectionChanged`... But I give the item selected and not the highlighted one.

I also try to cycling the elements in the ComboBox in the get of property that I bind (with Databinding) to the `ToolTip` property of `ComboBoxItems`, using a function like:

```
foreach (ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem in comboBox.Items)
{
    if (comboBoxItem.IsHighlighted == true)
    {
        //Do something          
        break;
    }
}
```

But I probably do something wrong... Because `comboBoxItem.IsHighlighted` it is always false...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this resources:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce14fc29-d320-4557-abc5-81b042730c48/how-to-get-current-combobox-item-on-which-mouse-overs-in-wpf

I found this solution:

In the WPF:

```
    <ComboBox
        Name="ComboBox1">
       <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">                    
                <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="OnMouseMove" />                        
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ComboBoxItem
            Content="Test1"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem
            Content="Test2"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

In the code behind:

```
private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem highlightedComboBoxItem = sender as ComboBoxItem;
        // highlightedComboBoxItem  is true
    }
```